# Arel::Tableの内容をActiveRecord_Relationにマージする方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

ユーザ(`User`)毎にグループ化した アクセスログ(`AccessLog`)一覧を作っております。
表示項目で 最新のアクセス日(`newest_accessed_at`)をArelで取得したのですが、
その内容を ActiveRecord_Relationに入れると classがArel::Tableとなり `.page`等のメソッドが実行できなくなります｡

ActiveRecord_Relationの内容に うまく Arelの内容をマージすることは可能でしょうか?

```
# model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :access_logs
end

class AccessLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

# model or controller
  @access_logs = AccessLog.all
  @access_logs = @access_logs.group(:user_id).project(arel_table[:accessed_at].maximum.as('`newest_accessed_at`')) # ここでclassがArelになる
  # @access_logs = @access_logs.group(:user_id).select("`access_logs`.*, max(`access_logs`.`accessed_at`) AS `newest_accessed_at`") # mysqlエラー
  @access_logs = @access_logs.page(10) # Arel::Tableだと `.page`が呼び出せない

# views
  <% @access_logs.each do |access_log| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= access_log.user.id %></td>
      <td><%= access_log.user.name %></td>
      <td><%= access_log.newest_accessed_at %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectメソッドも下記のようにArelのオブジェクトを引数に取れるようです。Rails 4.2で確認をしました。一度試してみてください。

```
@access_logs.group(:user_id).select(arel_table[:accessed_at].maximum.as('`newest_accessed_at`'))
```

Answer (score 0):

arel を where に繋ぐ、という回答になっていませんが、目的を達成するのであれば、下記が使えると考えます。

```
AccessLog.group(:user).maximum(:accessed_at).each do |user, newest_accessed_at|
  p user.id
  p user.name
  p newest_accessed_at
end
```